# Solidify modifier turning circle into oval

Tags: distort, solidify-modifier

I've have a solidify modifier on a hollow cylinder which has circle holes cut in it, the problem I'm having is that the inner circles are being distorted into an oval shape and I'd like to keep it circular. Any way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is because the solidify modifier appears to be verging inwards from the X & Y axis but not the Z, the oval is hardly noticeable in the beginning, is there a reason you need it to be a perfect circle?

Comment: I could get away with it not being a perfect circle but it's more of a learning thing. I know why it's getting distorted I just thought there's an easy fix but it seems like I'll need to add the boolean after the solidify get a clean result.

Comment: In that case, its just basic geometry. Simply apply the modifier and scale the outside on the Z axis, until you get your circle :)