# Issue with solidify modifier being uneven

Tags: normals, solidify-modifier

I'm trying to apply a solidify modifier to the following shape:
[image: Shape I want to apply solidify modifier to]

However, when I do add it, the thickness is not constant:
[image: Uneven diameters]

[image: Xray view: parts are too thin]

This is a problem, as  am planning to 3D print this, and this would be less than the minimum thickness my printer is able to print.

I've attached the blend file to this. Please help!

Blend File:
[image]

Comment: I've tried using [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250386/solidify-modifier-turning-circle-into-oval?rq=1) solution, however since I have a much higher poly count, it makes it unreasonable to do this. I cannot select them all at once because they are at various thicknesses, so if I scale them all the same amount, the problem will continue

Comment: Your tube  is carrying an object-level, non-uniform scale transform ..(by _far_ the most common reason folks post here about 'anomalous' modifier behaviour). Every time you scale in Object Mode during modelling, a little alarm bell should go off in your head. Scale the mesh, not the object, in Edit Mode. TLDR; Ctrl-A apply the scale of your model, which bakes the object transform into the mesh